# Get current directory of file after getting called by another bash script

Tags: bash, directory, pwd

So I have one bash script which calls another bash script.
The second script is in a different folder.

```
script1.sh:
"some_other_folder/script2.sh"
# do something

script2.sh:
src=$(pwd) # THIS returns current directory of script1.sh...
# do something
```

In this second script it has the line `src=$(pwd)` and since I'm calling that script from another script in a different directory, the `$(pwd)` returns the current directory of the first script.

Is there any way to get the current directory of the second script using a simple command within that script without having to pass a parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a SO FAQ: [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Comment: One comment on terminology.  Current working directory refers to the single runtime value for each process - the directory in which it is running (i.e. answering the question, where is ".").  A better way to ask the question is, "how do I locate the directory from which the second script is being executed".

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in?rq=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this to see if it helps

```
loc=`dirname $BASH_SOURCE`
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are looking for `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`, `readlink`and `dirname` (though you can use bash string substitution to avoid dirname)

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat b.sh
#!/bin/bash

./tp/a.sh

[jaypal:~/Temp] pwd
/Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat tp/a.sh
#!/bin/bash

src=$(pwd)
src2=$( dirname $( readlink -f ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} ) )
echo "$src"
echo "$src2"

[jaypal:~/Temp] ./b.sh
/Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp
/Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/tp/
```